# 96 Dakota V6 transmission work in a 94 318 v8 Dakota

Tags: transmission, dodge, swap, dakota, part-interchange

I have a 94 Dodge Dakota with the 318 in it. The transmission just went out. I found a 96 Dakota but with a V6 but same transmission as mine the A518. Will the transmission from the 96 fit with my 94 v8